# searching for jquery

Tags: jquery

The site for the extruder jquery has another function on their side that is not provided by their jquery:
http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.extruder/extruder.html
I've been searching for a way to create the sliding image they have on the left side of the screen, the one that pops out a little bit when hovered (and goes back when un-hovered) but preferably sends the user to a page when clicked on instead of the function they use, a popup.

Does anyone have any ideas of what script/css tricks i might use to get something similar for my website?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check `jQuery.animate()` method. As a param you must put a literal object with CSS styles.

E.q.:

```
// showing
$.css("position","absolute").animate({
    top: 30,
    left: 0,
    // ... etc.
});

// hiding
$.animate({
    left: "-500px"
});
```

It's easy. You only can't change colours using animate function. The rest of CSS properties are available.

Comment: possibly beyond the scope of the OP but in fact with the jquery.colors plugin, you can!

Comment: You're right, but I thought about $.animate() and 'clear' jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Found this